# converting a method to a function with a pointer to the struct in Golang

Tags: go

I read some strange codes which convert a method to a function whose first argument is a pointer to this method's struct.

I write an example to demonstrate it:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type fooS struct{}

func (s *fooS) fooF(fooArg interface{}) {
    fmt.Println("fooF: ", fooArg)
}

type wowS struct {
    callback func(s *fooS, fooArg interface{})
}

func main() {
    wow := new(wowS)
    wow.callback = (*fooS).fooF // strange
    wow.callback(nil, 123)
}
```

[Golang Playground Link](https://play.golang.org/p/NVsz_JgE2K)

The example's syntax is strange but has no error.

Can any one tell me how these codes work or give me an official document about them?

Thanks:)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Method expressions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_expressions):

> If `M` is in the method set of type `T`, `T.M` is a function that is
>   callable as a regular function with the same arguments as `M` prefixed
>   by an additional argument that is the receiver of the method.
>
> ```
> MethodExpr    = ReceiverType "." MethodName .
> ReceiverType  = TypeName | "(" "*" TypeName ")" | "(" ReceiverType ")" .
> ```
>
> Consider a struct type `T` with two methods, `Mv`, whose receiver is of
>   type `T`, and `Mp`, whose receiver is of type `*T`.
>
> ```
> type T struct {
>   a int
> }
> func (tv  T) Mv(a int) int         { return 0 }  // value receiver
> func (tp *T) Mp(f float32) float32 { return 1 }  // pointer receiver
>
> var t T
> ```
>
> The expression
>
> ```
> T.Mv
> ```
>
> yields a function equivalent to `Mv` but with an explicit receiver as
>   its first argument; it has signature
>
> ```
> func(tv T, a int) int
> ```
>
> That function may be called normally with an explicit receiver, so
>   these five invocations are equivalent:
>
> ```
> t.Mv(7)
> T.Mv(t, 7)
> (T).Mv(t, 7)
> f1 := T.Mv; f1(t, 7)
> f2 := (T).Mv; f2(t, 7)
> ```
>
> Similarly, the expression
>
> ```
> (*T).Mp
> ```
>
> yields a function value representing Mp with signature
>
> ```
> func(tp *T, f float32) float32
> ```
>
> For a method with a value receiver, one can derive a function with an
>   explicit pointer receiver, so
>
> ```
> (*T).Mv
> ```
>
> yields a function value representing `Mv` with signature
>
> ```
> func(tv *T, a int) int
> ```
>
> Such a function indirects through the receiver to create a value to
>   pass as the receiver to the underlying method; the method does not
>   overwrite the value whose address is passed in the function call.
>
> The final case, a value-receiver function for a pointer-receiver
>   method, is illegal because pointer-receiver methods are not in the
>   method set of the value type.
>
> Function values derived from methods are called with function call
>   syntax; the receiver is provided as the first argument to the call.
>   That is, given `f := T.Mv`, `f` is invoked as `f(t, 7)` not `t.f(7)`. To
>   construct a function that binds the receiver, use a function literal
>   or method value.
>
> It is legal to derive a function value from a method of an interface
>   type. The resulting function takes an explicit receiver of that
>   interface type.

---

And see:
[Go - difference between parameter and receiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17932722/go-difference-between-parameter-and-receiver)
[Is there a performance penalty for passing "this" by value in Go methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15326185/is-there-a-performance-penalty-for-passing-this-by-value-in-go-methods)
[differences between pointer and value slice in for-range loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39546804/differences-between-pointer-and-value-slice-in-for-range-loop)